# Why escaped single quote doesn't work in grep?

Tags: regex, grep, sed

I am trying to match a string:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'helloTitle' -m 'helloMessage' -n 'myApp' -sw
```

with:

```
crontab -l | grep '^[^#].*/usr/local/bin/growlnotify.*\-n \'myApp\'.*$'
```

it doesn't work:
nothing matched.

But:

```
crontab -l | grep '^[^#].*/usr/local/bin/growlnotify.*\-n.*$'
```

works very good:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'helloTitle' -m 'helloMessage' -n 'myApp' -sw
```

What is the problem with `\'myApp\'` ?

How to escape a single quote in grep/sed?

Comment: -1 you really should've used a simpler example to demonstrate your point

Answer (score 3):

one can escape single quote with `-e` option and using **hexadecimal** representation:

```
echo -e '\047'
> '
```

or in grep using **hexadecimal** representation and `-P` option:

```
crontab -l | grep -P '^.*/usr/local/bin/growlnotify.*\-n \047myApp\047.*$'
> * * * * * /usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'helloTitle' -m 'helloMessage' -n 'myApp' -sw
```

**ss64** as reference:

```
-P
   --perl-regexp
       Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression.
```

Comment: If you are using GNU grep, you could have also replaced the single quotes `'` enclosing the expression with double quotes `"` (2 chars modified) and removing the backslashes ```\``` (3 chars removed). Copy/paste proof `echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/growlnotify -t 'helloTitle' -m 'helloMessage' -n 'myApp' -sw" | grep "^[^#].*/usr/local/bin/growlnotify.*-n 'myApp'.*$"`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but you cannot escape single quotes inside single quotes.  You'll need to use double quotes.
You can prove it to yourself by doing:

```
echo '\'' <-- doesn't work
```

Your shell will expect another quote.

Comment: To clarify: "\" cannot be used to escape _anything_ inside single quotes. This is not a grep/sed issue; this is a shell issue (bash, csh, etc…).